I2C unexpected STOP condition
The I2c data transmission is stopped unexpectedly. I guess the master detect STOP condition and stop outputting the SCL. Is it possible that the slave device pull SDA to HIGH at the wrong timing (SCL is HIGH) causing a STOP condition?


The waveforms look like they have quite slow edges compared to clock rate. You cut off the timescale from the Logic capture and don't mention the clock speed. Or anything else about the circuit. And this transmision is between which two chips, and did you program the code?

This is a difficult to interpret without how knowing what your controller is doing or if the design of your transmission line is not providing the proper solution so I don't know if this is answerable. It's possible that your peripheral is pulling your SDA high at an incorrect moment, so your controller would see this as an opportunity to execute a STOP condition.

No I2C device can "pull SDA high" (or SCL, for that matter). All it can do is release its pulldown and allow the external pullup to raise the voltage.
